# Midnight Commander function keys not working

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal.app, midnight-commander

I'm using Midnight Commander in a Mac Terminal. I'm using PC keyboard, so function keys work as <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys, but they don't work in MC. I tested what character sequence is sent with each function key and it is the same as on my Linux machine. For example:

```
# cat
^[[15~  (F5)
^[[17~  (F6)
^[[18~  (F7)
```

Looks the same as on Linux machine.

I know I can hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then <kbd>0</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> keys to send <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd> but it's really awkward and counter productive.

I also have similar issue with <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> and <kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down keys</kbd>.
I managed to make <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> work in console, but they don't work in Midnight Commander. <kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd> doesn't work at all.

```
# cat
^A     (Home)
^E     (End)
^[[5~  (Page Up)
^[[6~  (Page Down)
```

**Note that I'm not using Midnight Commander on Mac OS X. I'm logging via SSH to remote machines running various flavors of Linux.**

Comment: i've got the same problem, i'm thinking perhaps karabiner has a way to fix this